# SVN Copy: Create destination path if it doesn't exist

Tags: svn, copy

Is there some option I can use to create a directory in case it doesn't exist when I'm copying a directory within a SVN server to another directory within the same server? For example:

`svn copy file:///home/svn/folder/app/trunk file:///home/svn/folder/app/branches/release`

...when there's no /branches/ folder? I know I can do it if I just wanted to create a single level directory (it would work if the command stopped at "/branches" however I want to copy it further into "release"). However if I try that command it will complain about the lack of a /branches/ folder to create the /release folder in.

Any solution either obvious or creative to this? I'd just like something that creates the path structure I specify if it finds it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add the `--parents` option to the `svn copy` command (type `svn help copy` for more details and other things you can do with copy).